# javascript error. uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write an anchor tag in a `for` loop, and sending parameters to a function in `onclick` event.

Now the problem is that the function does not pass the parameter which is in a variable instead it is getting an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: I is not defined ", where I is the value in the variable catidone.

```
catlisttxt += '<li>'+catidone+'<a href="#" onclick="return DisplayQues('+ catidone +')">'+data.categories[i].maincatname+'</a></li>';
```

Comment: Don't use `onclick` attributes. It makes life easier.

Comment: Why not. If you are a new guy learning Javascript,you might want to. Sure, Jquery.click is good, but you need to know about it in the first place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
catlisttxt += '<li>'+catidone+'<a href="#" onclick="return DisplayQues(\''+ catidone +'\')">'+data.categories[i].maincatname+'</a></li>';
```

Try escaping the quotes. I think when you do this, it actually sees this as DisplayQues(I) instead of DisplayQues('I')